# ServiceWorker in infinite loop

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I am creating a project where I have a serviceWorker that every **`2`** seconds sends a request to an API in php and if the answer is `"hi"` it shows a notification but if you close the browser and reopen or spend around 1 minute *serviceWorker* stops.

It works even with the page closed, but only as I said earlier for only **`1`** minute. Does anyone know how to make the *serviceWorker* not stop or at least have a longer duration?

### Code:

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  setInterval(() => {
    fetch('teste.php').then(function(response) {
      return response.text();
    }).then(function(data) {
      var options = {
        body: 'Ja gastaste 4GB do teu tarifario, mas va ainda tens 1GB',
        icon: 'https://cdn130.picsart.com/274112228042211.png?r1024x1024',
        vibrate: [100, 50, 100]
      };
      if (data == "oi") {
        if (Notification.permission == 'granted') {
          return self.registration.showNotification('IMM | Limite de internet', options);
        }
      }
    });
  }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: maybe try to use Web Workers ?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: @MoxGeek - I don't think you understand what `Web Workers` are for... **Totally unrelated**

Comment: I do **not** understand why you need a *service-worker* for the thing you're trying to do.

Comment: @vsync , i use web workers , maybe i didn't understand the question . :)

Comment: @MoxGeek - I don't think anybody understands the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `install` event is only triggered on »**install**«, so if you leave the page and reopen it, the service worker is already *installed*, that is why it does not start to request the server again.

If you want your *service worke*r to (re)start on page visit, you can send a message to it, or bind that activity to a certain request, like `/` in this case. So whenever the browser has loaded the index of your page it starts to poll. But if the page is already open, a message should do.

The »**right**« approach for your problem would be [Background-Sync](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/background-sync) but as far as I can see, it is [poorly supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=background-sync). So, you have to work around that limitation.